# How do I resolve "[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module" when using D3.js 7.0.0 with Next.js 11.0.1?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, next.js, node-modules

When trying to use D3 with Next.js, I cannot get past this error when using D3.js v7.0.0 with Next.js v11.0.1.:

> [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module

- I tried `next-transpile-modules` with no luck
- I got D3.js v7.0.0 to work with `create-react-app` but I need D3 working with Next.js v11.0.1

I installed D3.js using `npm i d3`. I'm importing with `import * as d3 from "d3"`. Using Node v15.8.0 and React v17.0.2

Comment: Still not sure why D3.js v7 and Next.js v11 won't play nice together. Based on a suggestion from the D3 Slack community I downgraded to **D3.js v6.7.0** Now `import * as d3 from "d3"` works with the `useEffect` React hook to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Downgrading d3 also worked for me!

Comment: Happening to me as well. Has there been a bug files with NextJS or D3?

Comment: @Ray is there an issue open somewhere? This is quite severe isn't it?

Comment: I have the same issue when importing d3 7.0.0 components from Electron through 'esm' utility (long story - it's hard to get Electron to natively load in esm mode). Downgrading to 6.7 helped. I suppose 7.0 has some aggressive detection of esm loading mode, which breaks the way 'esm' lib does it.

Comment: note, that dynamic import works for d3@7: `const d3 = await import("d3")`

Answer (score 2):

if you only need "import" from ES6+ features just add `'type': 'module'` in your **package.json** file. Otherwise use **babel** for enabling all ES6+ features for your app.

Answer (score 2):

Since v12, Next.js has native support for ES modules. So if anyone is facing this issue, just upgrade your Next.js version. D3 and other packages that provide only the ESM entrypoints are now fully supported without any need to transpile them.

Reference: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#es-modules-support-and-url-imports

This support was experimental in Next.js v11.1, and can be enabled using the following config:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  // Prefer loading of ES Modules over CommonJS
  experimental: { esmExternals: true }
}
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11-1#es-modules-support

Answer (score 1):

For new versions use the `'loose'` option

```
module.exports = {
    // Prefer loading of ES Modules over CommonJS
    experimental: { esmExternals: 'loose' }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was very strange as the error only manifested when clean restarting the project and refreshing browser. While I was developing, everything was fine - probably because of HMR, which loads components dynamically.

Solution in my case was to use dynamic loading, which was also hinted by the error message:

```text
Server Error
Error: require() of ES Module ... from ... not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in ... to a dynamic import() which is
available in all CommonJS modules.
```

#### the solution

```
// before
import { ResponsiveBar } from '@nivo/bar'

// after
const ResponsiveBar = dynamic(() => import('@nivo/bar').then(m => m.ResponsiveBar), {
  loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
  ssr: false,
})
```